# Correct way of using a Structure in C#

Tags: c#, struct

I am trying to handle a simple structure. All that i need to have all variables right in the structure which are later gonna be used as a connection string. I am not going to assign any new values to the listed variables. I know how to do the same with classes but now i wish to discover how to hit is with structs. Also, i don't need these parameters string p1 etc in the constructor but without them, i am getting an error. Please help)

```
public struct ConnectionString
{
    // vars declaration
    public string ip, login, password;

    // struct constructor
    public ConnectionString(string p1, string p2, string p3)
    {
        ip = "192.168.1.1";
        login = "boris";
        password = "123456";
    }
}
```

But when i call it, i've got an empty output:

```
ConnectionString ss = new ConnectionString();
Console.WriteLine("connection string: " + ss.password);
```

Comment: Okay, but what is your question?  What are you having problems with?  *Why* do you want to use a struct for this?

Comment: "how to do this with structs" : NOT. Structs are for special cases, this is not one of those. Value type semantics are of no use here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman what are those cases?

Comment: Also, public fields with camelCasing break mutiple rules.

Comment: You are creating your `ConnectionString` object without using the 3-parameter constructor, so of course none of it is populated.

Comment: @Amy i would like to use the mentioned struct as the connection string.

Comment: @DiegoSlinger i'm not sure what you're responding to, but that does not answer any question i have asked nor does it provide any new information i didn't already have.

Comment: @DiegoSlinger: You forgot to pass any values to your constructor.  As a result the code is using the implicit parameterless constructor.  You also forgot to *use* any parameters that you pass to the constructor.

Comment: "what are those cases" : I'm not going to write a tutorial here, Google. But bypassing a required constructor, as @Amy pointed out, is one 'solution' you don't have the problem for.

Comment: This is worth a read:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414906/what-are-the-differences-between-value-types-and-reference-types-in-c

Comment: @Amy these 3 parameters in the constructor are not used at all. I've mentioned it. I put them there otherwise i am getting an error. Variables Ip, Login and Password are already given a value. ip = "192.168.1.1";
  login = "boris";
  password = "123456";

Comment: Why don't you remove them?  You aren't using them anyway.  `public ConnectionString()`?  No, you are only giving those 3 fields values **when that constructor is called**.  You are **not** calling that constructor.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your constructor, check that `ip = "192.168.1.1";` is never executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I define a default constructor for a struct in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333829/why-cant-i-define-a-default-constructor-for-a-struct-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> // struct constructor
> public ConnectionString(string p1, string p2, string p3)
> {
>     ip = "192.168.1.1";
>     login = "boris";
>     password = "123456";
> }
> ```
>
> But when i call it, i've got an empty output:
>
> ```
> ConnectionString ss = new ConnectionString();
> Console.WriteLine("connection string: " + ss.password);
> ```

You are not calling the constructor you defined; you're calling the implicitly-generated default constructor, which is why none of the fields are populated.

EDIT: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs), note the following:

> Within a struct declaration, fields cannot be initialized unless they are declared as const or static.

Options:

1) Delete your constructor and declare the fields `const` and provide values, i.e.

```
public struct ConnectionString
{
    // vars declaration
    public const string ip = "192.168.1.1";
    public const string login = "boris";
    public const string password = "123456";
}
```

2) Populate those fields after calling the default constructor,

3) Call the constructor (with parameters) you defined,

4) (best option) not use structs for this problem.

Reference: [Using Structs (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs)

Comment: No problem. Consider clicking the green check mark next to the answer if you'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using parameters passed in the constructor inside it, you can call it as shown below. [As others have already commented, getting connection string is not something, you should do with struct.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) Structs are generally used when a group of related parameters and functionality are to be collectively used, and made available as set for smaller scopes of call. They are passed by value, not by reference.

```
ConnectionString connect = new ConnectionString("","","");
Console.WriteLine("connection string: " + connect.password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
public ConnectionString(string p1, string p2, string p3) .....
```

use:

```
public static ConnectionString Create()
{
    return new ConnectionString { ip = "a", login = "b", password = "c" };
}
```

and use:

```
ConnectionString ss = ConnectionString.Create();
```

This is assuming you must use a struct at all, of course.

Comment: If i call the constructor like you said: ConnectionString ss = new ConnectionString.Create(); I am gettig an error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0426 The type name 'Create' does not exist in the type 'ConnectionString' SadRecreate

Comment: @DiegoSlinger You have to add the code before it (`public static ConnectionString Create()......`) inside the struct `ConnectionString`.

Comment: my code looks like this:namespace StarterProject
{

 public struct ConnectionString
 {
  // vars declaration
  public string ip, login, password;

  // struct constructor
  public static ConnectionString Create()
  {
   return new ConnectionString { ip = "a", login = "b", password = "c" };
  }

 }
}

Comment: @DiegoSlinger And you still get the error `The type name 'Create' does not exist in the type 'ConnectionString' `? If yes, then I don't know.