# Exception in thread main with no errors in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]This error started randomly after making a change in my program. There are no errors being diplayed by Netbeans.

I've encountered random errors in Netbeans 8.2 before that were usually resolved by deleting the cache but I have deleted the cache, restarted Netbeans and still get the same error.

I performed a clean and build to no avail.

The program ran. I can still compile it and run it on a separate machine, but Netbeans keeps giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at rss.RSSFeedParser.main(RSSFeedParser.java:157)
....\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets  \run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

run.xml line 53

```
<java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
```

Update:
I was catching a "NumberFormatException" on my try catch. Netbeans threw no errors on this previously until all of a sudden. I changed it to "Exception". The program Runs fine, but I have a suggestion from Netbeans to change it back to "NumberFormatException". What gives here? I thought that as long as the required exceptions were caught, there would not be a problem.

Please see attached screen shots. [image: The problem] [image: The Solution]

Comment: It clearly says there is a problem in RSSFeedParser.java:157, it means check the line no 157 of RSSFeedParser.java class.

Comment: Please refer to the screen shot. There is no error in that program.

Comment: Try to understand between compilation error and Exception. Exception occurs at runtime, it means when you run the program.

Comment: In that line no either msEndPoint or msEndPoint.getTCPPorts() is null. While running, print those values. You will get the solution.

Comment: You have a RunTime Exception : RuntimeException is the superclass of those exceptions that can be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine. So... Compile != Everything will work fine.

Comment: When you change your `catch` block to catch `Exception`s, you're catching any error that is an instance of `Exception`, which includes `NullPointerException` (the actual error that you're getting). When you were just catching `NumberFormatException`, the `NullPointerException` would be thrown somewhere inside the `try` block and the `catch` block would not catch it, because the catch was only supposed to catch `NumberFormatException`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace you posted shows that there is an error at line `157` of the `RSSFeedParser.java` file. Your IDE isn't highlighting this line as erroneous because there aren't any *syntactic* or *compile-time* problems with your code.

```
String[] split = msEndpoint.getTcpPorts().split(",");
```

That code is "valid" in that it will compile, since the `split(String)` method of a `String` object returns an array of `String`s, etc.

What's actually going wrong is that either `msEndpoint` is `null`, or `msEndpoint.getTcpPorts()` is returning `null`, so java ends up trying to invoke a method on `null`, and then throws a `NullPointerException`. (More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).)

Your IDE probably won't be able to figure out every possible error that your program can throw when it runs, before your program runs. It can show compile-time errors though. (More on the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471837/what-is-the-difference-between-run-time-error-and-compiler-error).)

Try printing out the value of `msEndpoint` and then the value of `msEndpoint.getTcpPorts()` above your `String[] split = .....` line:

```
if(...) {
   try {
      System.out.println(msEndpoint);
      System.out.println(msEndpoint.getTcpPorts());
      String[] split = msEndpoint.getTcpPorts.split(",");
      ...
   }
}
```

See which one of those has a value of `null`.