# Compile time vs run time errors

Tags: java, runtime, compile-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Runtime vs Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time)

How should I know whether a specific line of code in Java may throw a compile time or run-time error? Assuming that the specific line of code anyway throws and error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Eclipse, compile time errors will be underlined in red. A compile time error is an error that is detected by the compiler. Common causes for compile time errors include:

- Syntax errors such as missing semi-colon or use of a reserved keyword (such as 'class').
- When you try and access a variable that is not in scope.
- When you declare multiple objects with the same name.

If the compiler detects any errors during compilation it will fail to build a new assembly (or class file in Java).

Even if your code has no compile time errors, errors can still occur on run-time. Errors such as 'logic errors' and 'runtime errors'. A good example of a runtime error is as followed:

- Pretend you're going to store an item in an array at index 5 but the array's size is only 4. The compiler won't detect an error here because it understands that the array size is subject to change but on run-time you'll be thrown an exception.

To detect which line exactly a run-time error occurs on you can use a combination of break points in Eclipse and proper exception handling.

Answer (score 6):

To see if your code doesn't compile, try to compile it. The compiler will complain.

To see if your code contains runtime errors, write unit tests.

Answer (score 5):

Practically every line of code may in theory throw a runtime exception and there is no such thing as "throwing a compile-time error". I believe you have mixed up compiler errors with runtime exceptions.

Anyway, the compiler errors are easy: compile it and see. There is never any "may" about them: a line of code definitely will, or will not, produce a compiler error.

As for a runtime error, the best you can do is statically analyze and **guess** whether a line of code will result in an error. Some cases are dead obvious, such as `throw new RuntimeException()` or `null.toString()`, but most aren't and require great experience to analyze without executing.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to compile it, then most of the compilers will point out all of the compile-time errors. Run-time errors on the other hand require greater effort from the developer.

Some compilers inform the user of the exceptions that maybe thrown, but the best way to find if a particular line of code contains run-time is run them with different inputs and observe the results(i.e use Unit Tests, sanity tests etc).

Comment: I hope every compile worth the name will point out *all* compile errors.

Comment: True, must have been careful with my words, correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your code, you will see wether there's a compile time error. Running the code might show runtime errors.