# Intro to Java - What's wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, int, double

First of all, I'm very new. So, I was able to get this to run when everything was int, but for some reason changing it to double, I can only input the first value and it errors. I don't understand why I can't do this:

```
        int datVal = Integer.parseInt(inNum);

        double [] iOne;
        iOne = new double[datVal];
```

There is no error until I run it or debug it. Here's what I've got:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class arStats2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double med, men, min, max;
        String inNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of data values:");

        int datVal = Integer.parseInt(inNum);

        double [] iOne;
        iOne = new double[datVal];

        double [] iTwo;
        iTwo = new double[datVal];

        int index=0;

        for (index=0; index < iOne.length; index++) {

            String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a data value:");
            int valIn = Integer.parseInt(value);
            iOne[index] = valIn;
        }

        System.arraycopy(iOne, 0, iTwo, 0, iOne.length);
        Arrays.sort(iOne);

        String out1 = "Sorted data: ";
        for (int i=0; i<iOne.length; i++) {
            out1 = out1 +iOne[i]+"";
        }
        out1 = out1 +"\n";

        String out2 = "Original data: ";
        for (int i2=0; i2<iTwo.length; i2++) {
            out2 = out2 +iTwo[i2] + "";
        }
        out2 = out2 +"\n";

        med = median(iOne);
        men = mean(iTwo);
        max = computeMax(iOne);
        min = computeMin(iOne);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, out2 +out1 +"Min Value: " +min +"\n"
                                        +"Max value: " +max +"\n"
                                        +"Median value: " +med +"\n"
                                        +"Mean value: " +men +"\n");
        }

    public static double median(double[] iOne) {

        double med;
        int index, indexHi, indexLo;
        if ((iOne.length %2) !=0) {
            index = iOne.length / 2;
            med = iOne[index];
        }
        else {
            indexHi = iOne.length / 2;
            indexLo = indexHi = 1;
            med = (iOne[indexLo] + iOne[indexHi])/2;
        }
        return med;
    }

    public static double mean(double[] iOne) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iOne.length; i++) {
            sum += iOne[i];
        }
        return sum / iOne.length;
    }

    public static double computeMax(double[] iOne) {
        double max = (iOne.length - 1);
        return max;
    }

    public static double computeMin(double[] iOne) {
        double min;
        min = iOne[0];
        return min;
    }
    }
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7.2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:456)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
    at arStats2.main(arStats2.java:25)
```

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: Might help you understand your error better if you research runtime vs compile time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time

Comment: I updated the question with the error. Sorry for excluding that when posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the values as double here:

```
 for (index=0; index < iOne.length; index++) {

        String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a data value:");
        double valIn = Double.parseDouble(value); // this line is changed
        iOne[index] = valIn;
    }
```

This will make it work with double values, but there are also other problems in your code, as pointed out by ValarDohaeris.

Comment: I tried parsing it as double before posting this. When I do that, it prompts me at the line:

iOne = new double[datVal];

to change datVal to int.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and added my modification. The output doesn't seem to be correct, but there are no warnings or errors in the code for me.

Comment: So what you did looks like this:

`double med, men, min, max;
String inNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of data values:");
double datVal = Double.parseDouble(inNum);
iOne[index] = datVal;
double [] iOne;
iOne = new double[datVal];`

Sorry. Like I said, I'm a newb. And I've e-mailed my professor 3 times with no response.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could be more specific about the error.
However, there are two parts of the code that I believe to be wrong:

```
indexLo = indexHi = 1;
```

should be

```
indexLo = indexHi - 1;
```

And in `computeMax()` you should have:

```
double max = iOne[iOne.length - 1];
```

Answer (score -1):

> but for some reason changing it to double, I can only input the first
>   value and it errors.

Well the reason is `datVal = Integer.parseInt(inNum);` expects an Integer and you are passing it a string that contains double which will result in a **NumberFormatException**  being thrown.

you should surround this with a `try{} catch {}` block and do something about that.

Comment: I didn't downvote! I wouldn't know whether it were right or wrong!