# design pattern run time structure VS compile time Structure

Tags: design-patterns, compile-time

I am reading the famous design pattern book by (Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides).

In fist chapter, How design patterns solve design problems.

I got stuck at Run-Time structure and Compile-Time structure. I did a bit of google on run time and compile time. Thanks to the link below
 [Runtime vs Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time)

However, What is the difference between **run-time structure** and **compile time structure**? 
and how it is related to design patterns?
Can anybody give me an example?
thanks

PS:
I know it is a beginner question so sorry in advance if it sounds silly to people

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At run time you care about the instances of objects, so anything that comes out of a new() method really. At runtime **behavior** (actual implementation) is important.

At compile time you care about the interfaces/classes, and how they can and should be connected. At compile time **type** (class/interface) is important.