# Android App Crash but source code shows no errors

Tags: android

When I compile it, there is no error showing in the Eclipse IDE. But When I run it, it keeps crashing. Why?

I don't know what to do since there are no errors showing. It just run and crush before it starts.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        this.initializeTextToSpeech("Hello World");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

        } else {
            tts = null;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to initialize TTS engine.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.d("onINIT", "started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void initializeTextToSpeech(String str) {
        if (tts != null) {
            String text = str;
            if (text != null) {
                if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my LogCat:

```
12-21 01:53:07.698: I/Process(1467): Sending signal. PID: 1467 SIG: 9 
12-21 01:53:07.870: E/Trace(1656): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 
12-21 01:53:07.962: D/AndroidRuntime(1656): Shutting down VM 
12-21 01:53:07.962: W/dalvikvm(1656): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa61d2908)
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testapp.testapp/com.testapp.testapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #11: You must supply a layout_width attribute. 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #11: You must supply a layout_width attribute. 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5614) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5756) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1190) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1028) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:70) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.testapp.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
12-21 01:51:16.462: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     ... 11 more
```

My code was based on this:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/teach-your-next-android-app-to-speak/

Comment: Show us your LogCat. That's how you debug something like this. It is crashing because it is executing code that is technically correct (can compile), but will still crash your app.

Comment: Why it can fail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time

Comment: I have added my logfile

Comment: `Binary XML file line #11: You must supply a layout_width attribute.`

Comment: Post your layout xml.

Comment: Many times it happens that your code is **syntactically correct**, but contains **logical errors**. Check against those ones.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is in the LogCat:

```
Binary XML file line #11: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

In one of the layouts you're refering to in your application, you don't define a `layout_width` attribute. Define it, and the error will go away.