# Why isn't the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a compile time error?

Tags: java, compilation, indexoutofboundsexception, compile-time

Can someone explain to me why `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a run-time exception instead of a compile-time error?
In obvious cases when the indexes are negative or greater than the array size, I don't see why it cannot be a compile-time error.

Edited: especially when the size of the array and even the indexing is known at compile time, for example `int[] a = new int[10]; a[-1]=5;` This should be a compilation error.

Comment: While you can pull out obvious examples that a compiler could catch they aren't the usual cause; its the sneeky ones that get you. I have never typed `a[-1]=5;` or similar. The 1-too-large for-loop over an array is pretty common for people starting out (especially if they come from a 1-indexed language) and it would be nice if that was caught but then the compiler is starting to actually run parts of the code to catch something that only novice programmes do. It all costs time in the compile stage

Comment: I agree that its good that the compiler is not checking for-loops regarding array indexing...but still a[-1]=5; should be a compilation error, like a[1.5]=5; when we use decimal numbers. I bet none of us used decimal numbers as index and its still not an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entering `a[-1] = 5;` is something only novices would do (as Richard Tingle said).  So it's not worth the effort to update the language standard just for that kind of error.  A more interesting case would be `a[SOME_CONSTANT] = 5;` where `SOME_CONSTANT` was defined as `static final int SOME_CONSTANT = -1;` (or some expression involving only constants that computes to `-1`) in some other class.  Even then, however, if the compiler flagged this as an error, it might catch cases where the programmer has put `a[SOME_CONSTANT] = 5;` in an `if` statement that has already checked for negative values of the constant.  (I'm assuming here that `SOME_CONSTANT` is a constant whose value could change if the application's requirements change.)  So while the language could, in theory, make it illegal to write an array indexing operation that can't possibly succeed, there are good reasons not to.

P.S. This is a real issue.  The Ada language does do some compile-time checking for static expressions that can't succeed, but it doesn't check this case, and there has been some discussion in the last few weeks about whether it should, or whether compilers should be allowed (but not required) to reject programs with array indexing that is known to fail.

Answer (score 6):

The size of the arrays may be defined only at runtime (for instance, the simplest case, if the size of an array depends on the user input).

Therefore it would be impossible to check at compile time for such kind of exceptions, by checking the accesses of an array without actually know its bounds (size).

Comment: I see, but when the size is defined at compile time and even the index is negative on compile time.... then why cannot the compiler generate an error message?

Answer (score 3):

Because it can't be detected at compile-time all the time.

Answer (score 0):

When working with pointers it's possible to have negative indexes and not have an error if you have correctly reserved the memory position you will access. Here is an example. When working with low-level programming languages things like this one are very frequently done but they don't have a lot of sense in high-level languages, at least for me.

```
int arr[10];
int* p = &arr[2];

int x = p[-2]; // valid:  accesses arr[0]
```

if you try to do:

```
arr[-5] //you will access and invalid block of memory, this why you get the error.
```

this may result a very helpful and interesting:

http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap7/subsection2.1.3.2.html

Comment: This, and other answers, don't address the question at all.  Of course the compiler couldn't catch it in this case; the question is, in a case involving a **constant** where the compiler **does** know for certain that it will throw an exception, why doesn't it give a compile-time error?

Comment: Your edit to the post is completely irrelevant.  This is a Java question, not a C question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check all indexes at compile time, because they can be variables and its values can change at runtime. If you have `array[i]` and `i` is the result of reading a file, you can evaluate `i` when executing the program. Even if you use a variable, remember that you can reassign your array changing its capacity. Again, this can be checked only ar runtime.

Check this question for more information: [Runtime vs Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time).

Answer (score 0):

As well as agreeing with the fact that array size can't be checked at compile time, I want to add another note on the limit of the size of an array, which is expected to be in the range of primitive `int`:

```
// This compiles, because the size evaluates to an integer.
int[] array = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1];

// This doesn't compile.
int[] array = new int[Long.MAX_VALUE];
```

And this error is because of `length` field (`int`) of arrays which are special Java objects.