# String array: 'The value changed at 'i++' is never used'

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
String[] queries = new String[2];
int i = 0;
Boolean result;
queries[i++] = "<query 1>";
queries[i++] = "<query 2>"; //Warning shown here
result = dbOpenHelper.ExecuteMyTransaction(queries);
```

The second `i++` gets highlighted and the warning *'The value changed at 'i++' is never used'* is shown. This code was written by another person, and to my knowledge, here `<query 1>` and `<query 2>` get assigned to `queries[1]` and `queries[2]` respectively, but then it must show an error, as the array is of size 2. There's no error and this kind of confuses me on what's happening here. Can I safely remove the second assignment, or change the first one to `queries[i]`?

Comment: use this: queries[i] = "<query 2>";

Comment: *`<query 1>` and `<query 2>` get assigned to `queries[1]` and `queries[2]`* array indices starts in 0, the values will be assigned to `queries[0]` and `queries[1]`. See also [post increment and pre increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is correct and you can safely ignore this warning or replace underlined `i++` with just `i`.

This warning simply indicates that as there's no further use of `i` variable in that scope, so incrementing its value or not makes no effect and is simply pointless.

Comment: Does that mean i is incremented after the assignment is done?

Comment: Yes. `i++` means post increment, which means first the `i` value is taken and used, then is incremented. If you want it incremented before use, then `++i` (pre increment) should be used instead.

Answer (score 6):

> i++ means post increment, which means first the i value is taken and used, then is incremented.

your code is correct you can ignore this warning and try below code to get out of this warning

```
String[] queries = new String[2];
int i = 0;
Boolean result;
queries[i++] = "<query 1>";
queries[i] = "<query 2>"; //change this here
result = dbOpenHelper.ExecuteMyTransaction(queries);
```

Answer (score 4):

The second `i++` could as well be `i` because `i` no longer is inspected.
The post-increment `i++` would return the current value of `i` and then increment i.

Answer (score 4):

> - but then it must show an error, as the array is of size 2.

If you try and access `queries[2]`, you would certainly get to know [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) . Though which is not the case with your current code.

> - There's no error and this kind of confuses me on what's happening
>     here.

The array bounds are not checked at the compile time but runtime as the size is allocated itself at runtime. More details on [Why isn't the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a compile time error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569056/why-isnt-the-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-a-compile-time-error)

> - Can I safely remove the second assignment, or change the first one to
>     queries[i]?

You can remove the assignment or as mentioned by others use post increment operator only in the first assignment as

```
queries[i++] = "<query 1>"; // index accessed is 0 here
queries[i] = "<query 2>"; // i=1 here
```

> - The value changed at 'i++' is never used'

This is a compile time warning since the compiler expects you to perform an operation on `i` further in the same scope where you are manipulating its value.

Answer (score 1):

> ++i increments i and then uses the variable. (Pre-increment)
>
> i++ uses and then increments the variable.(Post-increment)

In your codes, It's post increment operation.

```
queries[i++] = "<query 1>"; // It's equivalent to queries[0] = "<query 1>";
queries[i++] = "<query 2>"; // It's equivalent to queries[1] = "<query 2>";
```

So your code should be working fine as expected. However, it's always good  for 2nd query to be used as `queries[i] = "<query 2>";`

Comment: It doesn't fail to compile, but that doesn't change the fact that `i++` in `queries[i++] = "<query 2>"` is pointless.

Comment: As mentioned by other answers, it will be good if he can change it to queries[i] = "<query 2>";  But, as this code is legacy, so it's not doing any  harm as such. But it will be always good to change to queries[i] = "<query 2>";