# assert asserting when __debug__ == False

Tags: python, debugging, assert

I made a simple test program to test the functionality of assigning to `__debug__` using `globals()["__debug__"] = value` (`__debug__ = value` is a `SyntaxError`). It basically tries to raise an `AssertionError` and prints if the error was raised and whether or not it was expected. I did this as I ran in to issues with `__debug__` changing mid-program.

```
print("__debug__ is", __debug__)
exp = ["(expected)", "(not expected)"]
if __debug__:
    exp = exp[::-1]
try:
    assert False
    print("No AssertionError", exp[0])
except AssertionError:
    print("AssertionError", exp[1])
exp = exp[::-1]
globals()["__debug__"] = not __debug__
print("__debug__ is", __debug__)
try:
    assert False
    print("No AssertionError", exp[0])
except AssertionError:
    print("AssertionError", exp[1])
```

It produces unexpected results when run from command prompt, with and without the `-O` flag.

```
C:\Test>python assert.py
__debug__ is True
AssertionError (expected)
__debug__ is False
AssertionError (not expected)
C:\Test>python -O assert.py
__debug__ is False
No AssertionError (expected)
__debug__ is True
No AssertionError (not expected)
```

It seems that `__debug__` is changing, but `assert` is not actually checking if it has.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62048379/1959808

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You are not meant to change the value of __debug__**
As the note under [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/constants.html#__debug__) states:

> **Note:** The names [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/constants.html#None), [`False`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/constants.html#False), [`True`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/constants.html#True) and [`__debug__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/constants.html#__debug__) cannot be reassigned (assignments to them, even as an attribute name, raise [`SyntaxError`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError)), so they can be considered “true” constants

The reason this is happening is because `__debug__` is *not* evaluated at runtime, rather the `-O` command line flag is (At compile time). See also [Runtime vs Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time).

While you can change the value of `__debug__` through the hack `globals()["__debug__"]`, it does nothing, as the `assert expression1, expression2` doesn't *really* check for the value of `__debug__`. Supplying the `-O` flag assigns `False` to `__debug__` and removes all assert statements. That is to say, `assert` statements are removed by the `-O` flag, *not* the `__debug__` variable.

You can see this with `dis()` from `dis`. Using the following code:

```
import dis
dis.dis("assert False")
```

Without the `-O` flag (`path\to\file>python file.py`):

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (False)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        12
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (AssertionError)
              9 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

With the `-O` flag (`path\to\file>python -O file.py`):

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the `assert` statement is essentially removed from the code. Lines 0 to 3 with the `-O` flag are *identical* to lines 12 to 15 without. No where does it check for the value of `__debug__`.