# Running a Python script in optimized mode from another Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, compiler-optimization, assert

Is there a way to run a python script in optimized mode from another Python (Python 3) script?

If I have the following `test.py` script (which reads the [built-in constant `__debug__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__)):

```py
if __debug__:
    print('Debug ON')
else:
    print('Debug OFF')
```

then:

- `python text.py` prints `Debug ON`
- `python -OO text.py` prints `Debug OFF`

because of how the [constant `__debug__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__) works:

> This constant is true if Python was not started with an `-O` option. See also the `assert` statement.

Also, the value of `__debug__` cannot be changed at runtime: `__debug__` is a constant, as noted in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement). The value of `__debug__` is determined when the Python interpreter starts.

The following correctly prints **Debug OFF**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["python", "-OO", "test.py"])
```

But is there a more *pythonic* way?
The above doesn't seem very portable if the interpreter is not called `python`.

I've already searched here and the web without luck.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608386/1959808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `compile`

I've come up with a solution using the built-in function [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile), as follows.

Contents of the file `main.py`:

```py
with open('test.py') as f:
    source_code = f.read()
compiled = compile(
    source_code,
    filename='test.py', mode='exec', optimize=2)
exec(compiled)
```

Contents of the file `test.py`:

```py
if __debug__:
    print('Debug ON')
else:
    print('Debug OFF')
```

The output from running `python main.py` is:

```
Debug OFF
```

Possible values for the parameter `optimize`:

- `-1`: use same optimization level as the Python interpreter that is running the function `compile`
- `0`: no optimization, and `__debug__ == true`
- `1`: like `-O`, i.e., removes `assert` statements, and `__debug__ == false`
- `2`: like `-OO`, i.e., removes also docstrings.

Don't know if it's the best option, just sharing if can be useful fo others.

### Using `subprocess.run`

The `subprocess`-based approach is still more concise, and can be made portable by using [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable):

```py
import subprocess
import sys

if not sys.executable:
    raise RuntimeError(sys.executable)
proc = subprocess.run(
    [sys.executable, '-OO', 'test.py'],
    capture_output=True, text=True)
if proc.returncode != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(proc.returncode)
```

The above code calls the function [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

The check for the value of the variable `sys.executable` is motivated by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) of CPython:

> If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, `sys.executable` will be an empty string or `None`.

The check is implemented with a `raise` statement, instead of an `assert` statement, in order to check also in cases that the above Python code is itself run with optimization requested from Python, e.g., by using [`python -O`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-o) or [`python -OO`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-oo) or the environment variable [`PYTHONOPTIMIZE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE).

[When optimization is requested, `assert` statements are removed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement).

Using `raise` statements also enables raising an exception other than `AssertionError`, in this case [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError).

For running Python code that is within a function inside the same source file (i.e., inside `main.py`, not inside `test.py`), the function [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) can be used, together with the [option `-c` of `python`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c).

By the way better answers are welcome!