# Fully Typed Checked at Compile Time

Tags: compiler-errors, runtime-error, typechecking

I am having a hard time understanding the answers to this question.

Giving the following code:

```
int: size, size2, j;
float: x;
array[1:30] of int: nums;
```

For each assignment statement below, circle can or cannot to say whether it can or cannot be fully type-checked at compile time. Assume that an array’s subscript range is considered part of its type. Assume that numeric overflow is not considered a type-error.

```
 A. size = size2 + 1; --> Answer: CAN
 B. x = size; --> Answer: CAN
 C. nums[j] = 33; --> Answer: CANNOT
 D. nums[3] = nums[4]; --> Answer: CAN
 E. nums[j] = nums[j+1]--> Answer: CANNOT
```

Now, compile time errors occur when the program is being converted into machine code where run time errors occur during a program's execution. I have also read up on the following stack overflow question regarding compile vs run time errors: [Runtime vs Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time). After researching both topics, I am still confused how the following answers were derived. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the question asks if the type checker "can"/"cannot" catch the logic error at compile time.

The type checker knows for sure A, D are valid and B is invalid (assuming no implicit conversion), so the type checker CAN determine the validity of these three statements.

However, for C and E the validity depends on the actual value of `j` (e.g. they are valid when `j == 1` and invalid when `j == 100`). So the type checker CANNOT determine if C and E are valid (because "an array's subscript range is considered part of its type").

---

Note that these answers are based on the assumption that the type checker is unable to determine / does not care about the value range of `j`. Some languages like [Ada](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/range) and [Pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Subranges) support the "range" type, so those type checkers could in principle statically check if C (requiring `j` having type `int range 1:30`) and E (requiring `j` having type `int range 1:29`) are valid.