# How can you make Xcode give an audio alert when the your code is finished running?

Tags: xcode

I have a source code that takes 2-3 minutes to compile/run. Is there anyway that I can make Xcode beep or give *any* form of an **audio** signal?

I don't want to modify my source code. I just want Xcode to give me an audio notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Xcode > Preferences > Behaviors

[image]

Comment: This works. But I assume it notifies upon *building* is finished. I was looking for something that would beep after *running* & *attaching*. Is that doable?

Comment: Oh never mind. I should just use the `Running` box from your image

Comment: Weird... I used all 3, build-succeeds & running-starts & running-completes and assuming that running complete would be the last. But instead running-complete happens first...when I hit the stop button OR exactly when I click the run/play button as if it means when the app is terminated, not finished its running. What does finished running mean?!?

Comment: I get the behavior you want by enabling "Generates output" in "Running": it beeps when the app runs and is attached to the debugger.

Comment: I was about to say that. :) But another question. What exactly does 'generates output' mean? It confuses me about the diff between compiling, running. I mean what does it mean for `running` to have a start and then also a generate output. If there is such a distinction, I would have thought that the *start* of `running` would overlap with the `build`/`compile`. (sorry if we deviated from the original question). FYI I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time) question before and just read it again...

Comment: I guess that "generates output" means "the app is active and attached" (meaning, it is able to output to the debugger). I agree it's not very clear.

Comment: It actually means that something was printed/logged to the debugger. Meaning your app can be on for 5 minute and log nothing, so no sound is triggered. The moment that you log something then it will make a sound. I assume someone can use to this to be notified only upon logs.