# Why negative size of array is not a compilation error but throws java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

java does not allow to initialize an array with negative size. For example:

```
int[] arr = new int[-1];
```

If this is already known, why it throws `NegativeArraySizeException` instead of compilation error? Just curious to know why java decides it to be thrown at runtime while it is known at compile time that it will fail.

Comment: for more expression: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This check could be performed at compile time only in situations when the size is specified as a constant expression. However, Java Language Specification requires this check to be done at run time:

> #### 15.10.2 Run-Time Evaluation of Array Creation Expressions
>
> At run time, evaluation of an array creation expression behaves as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - First, the dimension expressions are evaluated, left-to-right. If any of the
>   expression evaluations completes abruptly, the expressions to the right of it
>   are not evaluated.
> - Next, the values of the dimension expressions are checked. If the value of any
>   DimExpr expression is less than zero, then a `NegativeArraySizeException`
>   is thrown.

In deciding if a certain check should be performed at compile-time or not the compiler design team considers costs and benefits of the new feature. Since the compile-time check would not replace a run-time check, but would be performed in addition to it, the added benefit is marginal. It does not mean, however, that the feature should not be implemented in a future version of the compiler, only that the language designers did not prioritize it high enough to be implemented now.

Comment: This is a [Feynman-esque answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA): *I can tell you what, but I can't tell you **why***. This doesn't give a reason why it isn't done at compile time; there is no "reason", in all likelihood, other than they just didn't see the need to.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's exactly what I think is happening here. I was editing to mention this at the bottom. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @AndyTurner considering how many little optimizations are done by `javac` and the fact that this is un-common, probably they never felt the need to actually do it