# Can a c# script be compiled in Unity?

Tags: c#, scripting

How scripting language use interpreter because I have used Unity 3D and I made C# scripts in that but it was first compiled. Please Explain.

Answer (score 0):

A script needs to be compiled to machine code before it can be used. Your computer doesn't read the code you write, but rather it gets converted into a language your processor can understand (binary). This also will ensure that there are no issues with your code before it reaches runtime (unless logical). I suggest reading up on some programming basics. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time) that explains the difference between compile time and runtime fairly well