# Why ErrorBoundary needed in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What kind of errors does it handle, and is there any real-world scenario?

I read the docs but **it doesn't give a good example**.

And docs also mention it handles UI errors, but UI errors can be solved at development time, so exactly why do we need "Error Boundaries".

Answer (score 1):

> but UI errors can be solved at development time

UI errors can't be solved at development time, although typing like `Flow` & `Typescript` indeed help a lot, still, there may be run-time errors that usually come for the data server.

---

Error Boundaries used for **catching run time errors** and **displaying** a friendly UI.

> See [Compile time vs Run time errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time).

`ErrorBoundary` is a class components that implements [`getDerivedStateFromError`](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) and `componentDidCatch` in order to add additional render on fall back UI.

> Currently, it can **only be implemented** with a class component, typically its the only class component in your application, the rest is function components with hooks.

In real-life use cases, you wrap your application with some `<ErrorBoundary/>` component and render the desired UI.

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false,
    error: { message: '', stack: '' },
    info: { componentStack: '' }
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError = error => {
    return { hasError: true };
  };

  componentDidCatch = (error, info) => {
    this.setState({ error, info });
  };

  render() {
    const { hasError, error, info } = this.state;
    const { children } = this.props;

    return hasError ? <ErrorComponent/> : children;
  }
}

<ErrorBoundary>
  <App/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Answer (score 1):

Error Boundaries are like `try-catch` blocks for react components . They allow you to catch and handle unexpected errors in react components gracefully, for example, display a message to the user that something went wrong.

These errors, if not handled will crash your app. Error boundaries allow you to catch those errors and handle them in a way that prevents your app from crashing and instead provide a user friendly message to the user indicating that something went wrong.

Keep in mind that Error Boundaries do not handle errors for:

- Event handlers
- Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
- Server side rendering
- Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

Here's a nice [article](https://alligator.io/react/error-boundaries/) that explains error boundaries