# Expression expected fromJson method

Tags: java, android

I don't know why I can't put T as parameter in **fromJson** method.

```
public class AbstractResponseListener<T> implements Response.Listener<String> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        T abstractObject = gson.fromJson(response, T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because [generics get erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Also, method [`Gson.fromJson(...)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class)) expects a `String` and a `Class`-object. `T` is not a `Class`-object.

Comment: `T` is a _type_. You also cannot use `Object` or `String` or whatever as the argument to the `fromJson` method. It needs a _class object_!

Comment: In this code snippet, the type parameter `T` does not make any sense. You are not doing anything with it! Did you mean `class AbstractResponseListener implements Response.Listener<String>` and `String abstractObject = gson.fromJson(response, String.class)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of "passing a type" in Java is to pass its [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) object.

There are several issues which do not allow you to pass `T` as a parameter to a method:

1. `T` is type, not an object, and as such cannot be passed as a parameter (or stored into a variable, which is virtually the same).
2. Even if the previous problem were not present, Java implementation of generics is *very limited* in a way called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). In short, it means that the actual "value" of of `T` (the *actual type*) is available only during [compile type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846103/2886891) (and the compiler performs type checks and decorates some calls with typecasting), but the type information is *erased* from the compiled code and is not available in [run time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846103/2886891).
3. The [`fromJson()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html) method signature (one of the many possible ones, the method is heavily overloaded) is

   ```
   public <T> T fromJson​(JsonElement json, java.lang.Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException
   ```

   so it expects as the second parameter a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) object. The possible syntactically correct usage would be e.g.

   ```
   gson.fromJson(response, String.class);
   ```

   or

   ```
   gson.fromJson(response, response.getClass());
   ```

   See more [Retrieving Class Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html).

---

And now when you know *why you cannot* do what you are trying doing :), you should consider *what you really want* to reach. Maybe you're a victim of an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) :)