# Sorting the array but getting the garbage value in the compiler. Also when done without function compiler return nothing

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

WAP to sort an array in ascending order.
Issue:  After Sorting the array getting the garbage value in the compiler. Also when done without a function compiler return nothing

```
#include<stdio.h>   
//Global Decleration   
int i, j, size;   
//Function for bubble sort   
int bubblesort(int arr[size]){  
    int temp;  
    printf("The numbers arranged in ascending order are given below: \n");  
    for(i=0;i<size-1;i++){  
        for(j=0;j<size-1-i;j++){  
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){  
                temp=arr[j];  
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];  
                arr[j+1]=temp;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)  
        printf("%d\n",arr[j]);  
}   
int main(){   
    int size, arr[size];    
    printf("Enter the number of elements of the array: \n");   
    scanf("%d", &size);    
    printf("Enter the numbers: \n");    
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){   
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);    
    }   
    bubblesort(arr[size]);     
}
```

Comment: `size` is uninitialized.  Turn on compiler warnings.  The things you seem to think are the compiler are actually your compiled program being executed.  The things you _should_ be seeing are the compiler screaming at you about uninitialized values because you've enabled all warnings.

Comment: Aside: this global use of variables is one of the least justifiable you could find! Anyway the `size` in `main` is *shadowing* the global `size`.

Comment: `bubblesort(arr[size]);` accessing out of bounds data. Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: Note that the global variable `size` is unrelated to the local variable `size` defined in `main()`.   The global variable is zero. The design of the interface to `bubblesort()` is broken — you need an interface more like `void bubblesort(size_t size, int arr[size])`, passing the array size explicitly.  There's no value to return, so using `void` is appropriate.  You should separate the printing from the `bubblesort()` function, too.

Comment: Another minor: try to keep *form* and *function* separate. The sorting function should really be silent - the reporting should be done by the caller.

Comment: Worth understanding [runtime vs. compile time](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/runtime-vs-compile-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time).