# Difference between Runtime and Compile time?

Tags: dynamic, compilation, static, runtime, compile-time

What is the difference between compile time and run time?
I am learning the differnce between static languages and dynamic languages. I read thatin statically typed
languages the type checking is performed at "Compile time",whereas in case of dynamically typed languages
type checking is performed at "Run time".What exacly is compile time?Does the code gets compiled as we write
the code in an IDE?or it is compiled after we are done writing code.
I m speaking in context of modern ide like vscode where we have the code runner extension to write code.

I have learned basic python and C language.I have observed that in C we have to mention the datatype while
writing the code but not in python.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime vs. Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time)